# public void sendMessage(View view)

Tags: android, view

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I am getting this Error: "View cannot be resolved  a Type

Comment: It looks like you're missing an import.  I'm guessing this is for Android, try adding "import android.view.View;"

Comment: It is for Android. So did import now I get this error "The method sendMessage(View) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse to work through the Android Developers Kit tutorial, this particular problem may occur, and may be resolved by doing a "Save All" to force something of a "rebuild" of your project.  At least, that's what worked for me. You can also invoke a rebuild after cleaning you project. Menu bar: `Project -> Clean...` select your project and click okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the imports section

import android.view.View;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your brackets{} are in the correct spot. This just happened to me and it was because it was actually inside another method declaration.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider leaving a comment instead.

Comment: That's a good idea. It says I need "50 reputation to comment' however.